# how to get file name and file details while uploading document

Tags: metadata

I have question related to Metadata, how to get file details and assign the meta data fields like Title, Year and month of Document while uploading. by using calculated fields or any how. i tried using (created) field in calculated field. but its giving error.

thanks.

Comment: do you want to retrieve document properties of a file? are you looking for the document properties of only ms office files or pdf as well?

Comment: Ya only Ms office files. that also while uploading.